# can anyone help me with c# required filed validation code?

Tags: c#, validation

Hello i am trying to find a 'C# required field validation' for my form.

can anyone give me some idea please?

There are 10 text box and 1 insert button,what i want to build is a stand alone application.

Comment: What validation you want to do? Please show us your code.

Comment: he is asking for Required Field Validation.

Comment: yes am looking for required field validation like if the user didn't put the company name... on one side of the txt box he will see please enter a company name pls... this things are ease on web application like php or asp.net but on C# i don't know.so if is there anything you recommend... let me know Thanks.

Comment: @Jegadeesh: When editing, please fix everything in a post that needs fixing, not only the tags. Also, don't try to keep changing tags until something gets approved. Please find the set of tags that is appropriate and suggest it _once_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# Code for Validation

```
protected void btnSubmitForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(txtSome.Text.Length==0)
   {
      label.Text = "your message for Required feild!";
   }
   else if(txt2.Text.Length==0)
   {
      label.Text = "your message for Required feild!";
   }
   else
   {
    //write code here to insert values in database. this block of code will be executed when your all text boxes will have some code. 
   }
}
```

Comment: okay Aftab thank you for the codes but am on this standalone application project and do u have any idea that validates textbox such as if you didn't put anything in textbox and click on insert, on one side of the text box you will see add some value to textbox one or please add name to text box...

Comment: ok so you are using Windows Application. Put a label in front of textbox. And on button click event check if(textbox.length==0){label.text="Your message";}

Comment: this code works exactly how i wanted!!! thanks Aftab Ahmed

Comment: hey this code works perfectly but when i click insert button message box will pop up that the record is successfully added and it will add NULL field to databse, what can i do about this???

Comment: properly use if-else statements. i have edited code so you can get an idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

RequiredFieldValidator:

```
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="YourControl" ErrorMessage="Error Message!!!!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: he is using windows application.

Comment: @AftabAhmed why is asp.net tagged then?

Comment: i don't know but he is looking solution for windows app. first i also used asp.net required field validator.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtName" />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSubmitForm" text="submit" onclick="btn_ClickSubmit" />
```

.cs

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtName;

protected void btn_ClickSubmit(object sender, Eventargs e) 
{
 if(txtName.Text =="")
  {
   MessageBox.Show("Textbox is required");
  }
}
```